# In the revisions, tag badge gets too faint background color once hovered

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, dupehammer

1. Find some question which was hammer-closed/reopened
2. Go to the [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/269767/revisions)
3. Hover over the badge.
4. The badge background gets too faint compared to the background of the revision entry, i.e. the badge and the entry backgrounds have almost the same color.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: [status-wheres-the-bug]

Comment: @Door [status-look-at-the-screengif]

Comment: I don't see any bug there.

Comment: @Door when you hover over the tag badge, the background of the badge almost matches the revision background, so it can be hardly seen.

Comment: You should make it clear that it's too faint **compared to the yellow-ish** background in the post itself. (best to add another gif)

Comment: (or just use [ordinary screenshot with FHRC](http://i.stack.imgur.com/amgX7.png) ;))

Comment: @Doorknob as always with dear nicael, it's one of those tiny design bugs that you never spot, but once spotted, you can't miss that anymore.

Comment: @Sha and everyone, tried to clarify.

Comment: With **pink** circle? Blasphemy! ;)

Comment: @Sha [status-by-design]